# Php format on save in Visual Studio Code

Tags: php, formatting, visual-studio-code

Can you `format on save` `PHP` as well with the `Beautify extension of Visual Code` ? If yes how do you set it up ? If not which extension does that?

Answer (score 3):

Try plugin [PHP Intelephense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bmewburn.vscode-intelephense-client) by Ben Mewburn. As the manual says:

> Lossless PSR-12 compatible document/range formatting. Formats combined
>   HTML/PHP/JS/CSS files too.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`vscode-php-formatter`](https://github.com/Dickurt/vscode-php-formatter) extension which will format your PHP code either on demand (via key binding) or on save.

It's a wrapper for this [PHP Coding Standards Fixer](http://cs.sensiolabs.org), which as you can see allows for pretty flexible configuration, so you can adjust it to your tastes.

To add custom configuration, create a `.php_cs` file, add this to your argument settings:

```
phpformatter.arguments: ["--custom-config=/path/to/file/config.php_cs"]
```

And create a file with your custom rules:

```
<?php
$finder = Symfony\Component\Finder\Finder::create()
    ->files()
    ->in(__DIR__)
    ->exclude('vendor')
    ->exclude('resources/views')
    ->exclude('storage')
    ->exclude('public')
    ->notName("*.txt")
    ->ignoreDotFiles(true)
    ->ignoreVCS(true);

$fixers = [
    '-psr0',
    '-php_closing_tag',
    'blankline_after_open_tag',
    // more custom rules
];

return Symfony\CS\Config\Config::create()
    ->level(Symfony\CS\FixerInterface::PSR2_LEVEL)
    ->fixers($fixers)
    ->finder($finder)
    ->setUsingCache(true);
```

[Read more at the source](https://github.com/Dickurt/vscode-php-formatter/wiki/Configuration)

Answer (score 2):

Elaborating on Zain's answer, I'm writing PHP and React and want to auto format both.

First install "PHP Intelephense" extension to format PHP and the "Prettier" extension to format JS. Then open VS Studio Code's settings and:

1. click the icon in the top right corner to edit as JSON
2. Remove any generic default formatter setting
3. Add JavaScript and React formatter settings
4. Add PHP formatter setting
5. Save

[image: Step-by-step instructions]

Answer (score 1):

The capitalized '[PHP]' did not work for me. However, the lowercase did. Like this:

```
"[php]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "bmewburn.vscode-intelephense-client"
  }
```